# Jetpack Compose. Offset is unspecified on Redmi devices

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In my project I get a lot of those exceptions:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException
Offset is unspecified
```

These exceptions only appear on Redmi devices (tablets and handheld).
This issue is present from version 1.1.0 to the latest 1.2.0-beta03 of Jetpack Compose, so changing version is not an option.

There is a full stacktrace:

```
androidx.compose.ui.geometry.Offset.getX-impl (Offset.java:28)
androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.recalculateWindowPosition (AndroidComposeView.java:2)
androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.handleMotionEvent-8iAsVTc (AndroidComposeView.java:6)
androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.dispatchTouchEvent (AndroidComposeView.java:62)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3088)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2781)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3088)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2781)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3088)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2781)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:3088)
android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent (ViewGroup.java:2781)
com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent (DecorView.java:496)
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent (PhoneWindow.java:1853)
android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent (Activity.java:4072)
com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent (DecorView.java:454)
android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent (View.java:13744)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:5601)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess (ViewRootImpl.java:5401)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4902)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:4955)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4921)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:5061)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4929)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:5118)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4902)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext (ViewRootImpl.java:4955)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward (ViewRootImpl.java:4921)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply (ViewRootImpl.java:4929)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver (ViewRootImpl.java:4902)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:7654)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents (ViewRootImpl.java:7623)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:7584)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent (ViewRootImpl.java:7785)
android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent (InputEventReceiver.java:251)
android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents (InputEventReceiver.java)
android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents (InputEventReceiver.java:213)
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput (ViewRootImpl.java:7730)
android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:7809)
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1031)
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:854)
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:782)
android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:1016)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:883)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:100)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:223)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7562)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:539)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Anybody faced it?

Comment: i seen it on Redmi Note 4x (Android 7)

Answer (score 2):

I got this issue when i change touch area of a Composable dynamically when changing scale via Modifier.graphicsLayer{} and i also use `Offset.Unspecified` to not draw on Canvas initially for drawing apps.

If the issue is something happens on small region and negligible use

```
if(offset != Offset.Unspecified) {
    xCoor = offset.x
    yCoor = offset.y
   // or do drawing with offset here for valid values
```

If it's a behavior that never returns any value but Offset.Unspecified you should open an issue for it.

Answer (score 1):

I used to get this exception when my offset parameters are not a number.
Make sure that your Offset parameters are number.

Here is how you can check if it is a number :

```
if(offsetX.isNaN().not()){
//handle your code here
}
```

Comment: how can i get offsetX ?

Comment: @MahdiSafarmohammadloo Check where ever you use Offset and debug into x parameter of that Offset then you will see. I need to see the code for further help.

Comment: i didnt used offsetX , i have only a clickable button and i used rotationY in graphics layer to rotate my button , every things works ! but in redmi phone i got that exception .

Comment: @MahdiSafarmohammadloo can you share the rotationY calculation please?

Comment: i set rotationY = Animatable state's value , it change 0.0f to 360.0f with animation. error occurs when i clicked rotating button (it happened somethimes),
i set clickable to false before starting (changing rotationY) and enabled after it but i got error

https://github.com/mahdisml/WastedAndroidCodes/blob/main/buttonbug.kt

Comment: @MahdiSafarmohammadloo I could not get the expection but I assume that, there is algorithm leaking on **recalculateWindowPosition** function. I will let you know If I learn anything more.

Answer (score 0):

I got this issue without ever directly using the offset, but when using the ".rotate()" modifier, the problem was division by zero in the the .rotate() so it was trying to rotate by NaN.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).